# Do shareholder agreements have to be identical within the same company?

Tags: contract-law, shareholders

I am being told that the various potential shareholders must sign an identical shareholder agreement.

I have a problem with a clause relating to confidential information and have been told it cannot be changed specifically for me and that it must be identical for all. Is that true?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, a shareholder agreement that applies to all shareholders ought to have the same terms for everyone. The shareholder agreement signed by everyone could single you out for special treatment, but an agreement of everyone should be the same.